# Making the Guest List javascript

Tags: javascript

We need to keep track of the party guests, but the data we currently have combines the guests first and last names into a single name. You have been asked to separate the names to make the data easier to work with.

The function `makeGuestList()` takes an object with a name property whose value will be a string consisting of a first name and a last name, separated by a space. The function should return an `object`.

The function should remove the name property, replace it with `firstName` and `lastName` properties

And this is I could do so far

```
function makeGuestList(person) {
  var firstName = person.name.split(' ')[0]
  var lastName = person.name.split(' ').pop()
  return  person[firstName] = person[lastName];
}
```

for example :

```
makeGuestList({ name: "Hannah Fry", age: 46 })
```

Should return :

```
{ firstName: "Hannah", lastName: "Fry", age: 46 }
```

Comment: okay than what is your question? @karim

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to repopulate the object you were given with the first and last name separated.

This is best done by creating a new object and insert the new Properties and return this Object.

```js
function makeGuestList(person){
  var firstName = person.name.split(' ')[0];
  var lastName = person.name.split(' ').pop();
  return {firstName: firstName, lastName: lastName, age: person.age};
}

const person = {name: "Hannah Fry", age: 46};
let newPerson = makeGuestList(person);
console.log(newPerson);
```

Comment: It does return an Object like you defined it should return. I cant answer things, you didn't ask. If it doesn't work with the result you were asking for, then you need to be more specific in your question.